# How I resolve "Downloading VS Code Server failed" while using vs code on MacOs

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use remote development on VS code, but it has the follow error

```
SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+kf"
SSH Resolver called for host: kf
Setting up SSH remote "kf"
Using commit id "daf71423252a707b8e396e8afa8102b717f8213b" and quality "insider" for server
Install and start server if needed
> bash: no job control in this shell
> Installing...
> Downloading with wget
> ERROR: certificate common name “*.azurewebsites.net” doesn’t match requested host name “update.code.visualstudio.com”. To connect to update.code.visualstudio.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
> 1931c79d-3297-4f42-9eb5-6f8f91556ed9##25##
"install" terminal command done
Received install output: 1931c79d-3297-4f42-9eb5-6f8f91556ed9##25##
Server download failed
Downloading VS Code Server failed. Please try again later.
```

and how I can use "no-check-certificate" to wget VS Code Server?

Comment: this answer solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/57601121/2374691

Answer (score 12):

If you are behind a proxy, create a file named **.wgetrc** in your home directory and add the following lines:

```
use_proxy=on
http_proxy=http://<my-proxy.company.net:port>
https_proxy=http://<my-proxy.company.net:port>
```

If needed, for one time, add:

`check-certificate=off`

> **Note:** Disabling certificate check is not recommended as it can be a security threat.

Comment: I have been facing this issue and only check-certificate=off line worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Add a line of :

`check-certificate=off`

to your `.wgetrc` file under the user's home directory.

**Note**: It will disable the SSL certificate check for all wget commands you use, unless you change it to :

`check-certificate=on`

Answer (score 3):

**Configuring WSL behind proxy:**

I will provide my solution that works for me.
In WSL subsystem add file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` with proxy setting:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@server_addr:port";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@server_addr:port";
```

After that, add another setting in `~/.wgetrc` file:

```
use_proxy = on
check_certificate = off
http_proxy = http://user:password@server_addr:port
https_proxy = http://user:password@server_addr:port
ftp_proxy = http://user:password@server_addr:port
```

After that, try to install the Visual Studio Code plugin for `remote wsl`.
It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem this morning.
And I got some tricks to work around.

I got another machine with Linux, and it could connect to the Internet correctly. I connected to the Linux machine via remote-ssh connect successfully. I checked the home folder, and I found a folder with name `.vscode-remote`. And I copyed  this folder to the home path of the machine I got this problem, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

On my case, I was NOT using a proxy and running on a Windows 10 desktop. I just disabled my anti-virus.
Kaspersky was blocking the downloads.
Regards.