# WSL2 trying to launch VSCode with code . results in error "Please install missing certificates."

Tags: certificate, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wget, visual-studio-code, wsl2

I'm trying to launch VS Code from WSL2 using the command `code .`, the command spots that there is an update available for VS Code server and tries downloading it, however the download fails with a certificate error "Please install missing certificates." and recommends the command `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`, however this command finds no updates and does absolutely nothing.

There is a temporary "solution" to disable all certificate checks for every wget-command by typing `check-certificate=off` into .wgetrc in home, but I would have to insert the this to the file and then remove it every time VS Code updates.

Are there any actual solutions to this problem? I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1434294/how-i-resolve-downloading-vs-code-server-failed-while-using-vs-code-on-macos/1471492) thread without an actual solution, please don't mark duplicate.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?  If so, did you try the proxy answer mentioned in the question you linked?  You said that question was "without an actual solution", but you didn't mention what you tried from it (or didn't, if it wasn't applicable).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds the proxy solution required an address and usernames and I have no clue about any of that, so I guess I can't be behind a proxy? I don't have any recollection of being behind a proxy

Comment: Are you on a corporate or educational network?  The network administrators can automatically configure the proxy settings on your Windows machine through [WPAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-proxy-server-settings).  Given the error you are seeing, it would be worthwhile to check.  Start by typing *proxy* in your Windows Start Menu/Search, and select "Proxy Settings".  If it's getting a proxy configuration automatically, then see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/346376/1210833) for information on how to retrieve the WPAD script.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds it's a home network with a home license, the settings don't contain any values and proxies are off

Comment: Thanks for checking that, at least.  Every reference I find to "Please install missing certificates" seems to indicate that there is a proxy or firewall involved that is interfering with the certificate chain.  You could have a different root-cause, or it just could be manifesting itself in a different way.  Could you add more of the error output (in a code-block) to your question?  See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78478) for an example of the complete error history.